# Multi-Day All Day Events with Event Kit not at top of calendar

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit

All-day events that span multiple days in Event Kit are appearing at the bottom of the list of events for that day.

For example if I have a multi-day all day event from 1 January to 3 January and then look at the calendar for 2 January.

2 January

- 8-10am Meeting
- 12pm - 1pm Lunch
- All-Day Event*

**Code**

```
    let startDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(Dates.dateObject)
    let endDate = startDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(Double((60 * 60 * 24))

    let calendars = eventStore.calendarsForEntityType(.Event)
    var selectedCalendars = [EKCalendar]()

    for cal in calendars {
        if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(cal.calendarIdentifier) != false) {
            selectedCalendars.append(cal)
        }
    }

    let eventsPredicate = eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, calendars: selectedCalendars)

    events = eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(eventsPredicate)
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, the start date and end date for the predicate has to be 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 (rather than 00:00:00 to 00:00:00).

The code was modified as below.

```
    let startDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(Dates.dateObject)
let endDate = startDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(Double(((60 * 60 * 24) - 1))

let calendars = eventStore.calendarsForEntityType(.Event)
var selectedCalendars = [EKCalendar]()

for cal in calendars {
    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(cal.calendarIdentifier) != false) {
        selectedCalendars.append(cal)
    }
}

let eventsPredicate = eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, calendars: selectedCalendars)

events = eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(eventsPredicate)
```